# Java Threads with Observer pattern for long operations

Tags: java, multithreading, observer-pattern

In my application, I have two threads given ThreadA and ThreadB. ThreadA is a thread that holds and manipulates some data (the producer) and ThreadB is the corresponding consumer thread that reads from ThreadA (read-only).
I want to achieve that ThreadB informs ThreadA to update the data (which may take some time) and when the data is changed, ThreadB should get/request it from ThreadA. As long as ThreadA has not finished updating the data, ThreadB shouldn't wait but continue his work with the current (old) data he has.
Now my idea was to use the observer pattern to inform ThreadB that ThreadA has finished updating

```
public class ThreadA implements Runnable {

private boolean sometimesTrue = false;
private int[] someBigArray = new int[XXX];


private synchronized int[] getBigArray() {
    return this.someBigArray;
}

private void fireListenerDataChanged() {
    for(ThreadAListener l : listeners) 
        l.notify();
}

private synchronized void updateArray() {
    //do some stuff on the array that takes a lot of time
}

@Override
public void run() {
    while(true) {
        if(sometimesTrue) {
            updateArray();
        }
    }
}


public void doUpdate() {
    this.sometimesTrue = true;
}

}
```

```
public class ThreadB implements Runnable, ThreadAListener  {

private int[] bigDataToWorkOn;
private Thread threadA;

public ThreadB(ThreadA threadA) {
    this.threadA = threadA;
}

@Override
public void run() {
        //do my stuff with bigDataToWorkOn 
        if(sometimesTrue) {
            threadA.doUpdate();
        }
}


public void notify() {
    this.bigDataToWorkOn = threadB.getBigArray();
}      

}
```

My main goal was to avoid using some kind of BlockingQueue because then afaik ThreadB would wait with his work until ThreadA passes the data in the queue. The same problem would occur if I would call getBigArray in the while-loop in ThreadB because when ThreadA is currently working in updateArray, ThreadA would be locked and ThreadB would also wait for ThreadA to finish. So is this a proper approach?

Comment: *Is it a proper approach?* Does it work? Do you have any problems with it?

Comment: You may want to have a look at Guava's ListenableFuture. https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/ListenableFutureExplained

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This approach could be workable solution, except that fact, that you must mark field `sometimesTrue` with `volatile` modifier, if you don't want to have infinite loop inside your `run()` method of `ThreadA`.

Futhermore, if you don't want your `ThreadA` be eating 100% of single core, you have to add some delay into loop inside its `run()` method:

```
public void run() {
    try {
        while(true) {
            if(sometimesTrue) {
               updateArray();
            }
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
      // ... do something with e 
    }
}
```